# Multiple anchor/endpoints in jsPlumb

Tags: jsplumb

How do I add unlimited endpoints on an item?  I can only seem to add, say just for the top side: "TopLeft", "Top", and "TopRight".  How do I go about adding say 10 anchors on the top side?

This is how I add an endpoint

```
jsPlumb.addEndpoint("item1", {
  anchors:"TopRight"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at "makeSource" (resp. "makeTarget"):

"https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/apidocs/classes/jsPlumbInstance.html#method_makeSource

> Makes some DOM element(s) a Connection source, allowing you to drag connections from it/them **without having to first register any Endpoints**.

You can see this in the demo "statemachine": 
https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/blob/master/demo/statemachine/demo.js
https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/statemachine/index.html

The orange square in the sample allows to create a new connection. Without this, you can not really differ between drag&drop and creating a connection.

The number of connections in this sample is limited to 2. If you set this option to -1, you can have an unlimited count of connections without defining any endpoint.